# creating a TreeView for Mvc 5

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to MVC and I want a simple treeview structure with some dynamic data(list of folders and subfolders) in it. I have seen many example where data is being taken from Sql database which makes it bit too complicated. and I don't want that. I want just a basic tree view with dynamic data taken from controller. Even for now a treeview with static data will work fine. Some examples have used kendo which I am failed to understand correctly. Can someone please help me with the same.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: html doesn't have a native tree view, but there are plenty of examples online, usually based on nesting unordered lists `<ul>` and css rules. eg https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/plugins/treeview/